# Help editing JSON to make an array rather than a 'dictionary'

Tags: php, mysql, json

I currently have json using json_encode from a mysql query which looks like this:

```
{"post_2":{"caption":"...","id":"...","accountID":"..","date":"07\/07\/2011 1:45:12 AM","title":"...","authorInfo":{"Email Address":"..."}}}, {"post_2":{"caption":"...","id":"...","accountID":"..","date":"07\/07\/2011 1:45:12 AM","title":"...","authorInfo":{"Email Address":"..."}}}
```

How can I have the json being an array of posts ('post_2', 'post_1') rather than it being a dictionary? The JSON will be decoded on an iPhone using SBJSON and the JSON will have to be made into an array in the backend.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The example doesn't contain valid JSON (it's either incomplete or just plain broken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a non-associative array to `json_encode()`. The easiest way is usually to simply call `array_values()` on the (associative) array, and encode the result.

Comment: what do you mean by non-associative array?

Comment: associative = array("a"=>"apple","b"=>"banana"), non-associative = array("apple","banana")

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's [`json_decode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, specifically the 2nd parameter if you want an array.

Comment: I am decoding it on an iPhone using SBJSON, I don't think they have that function ;)

Comment: I think you might want to reword your question then.