# PHP JSON encoding turns key to string when unset

Tags: php, json

Can you guys help me explain what is happening here.

```
$data[0] = array("one" => "uno", "two" => "dos", "three" => "tres");
$data[1] = array("one" => "uno", "two" => "dos", "three" => "tres");

//unset($data[0]);

$encode = json_encode($data);

$decode = json_decode($encode);

var_dump($decode);
```

outputs:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["one"]=> string(3) "uno" ["two"]=> string(3) "dos" ["three"]=> string(4) "tres" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["one"]=> string(3) "uno" ["two"]=> string(3) "dos" ["three"]=> string(4) "tres" } }
```

This is normal keeps it as an array but as soon as I unset a part of the array it turns it into an obj.

```
$data[0] = array("one" => "uno", "two" => "dos", "three" => "tres");
$data[1] = array("one" => "uno", "two" => "dos", "three" => "tres");

unset($data[0]);

$encode = json_encode($data);

$decode = json_decode($encode);

var_dump($decode);
```

output:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["1"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["one"]=> string(3) "uno" ["two"]=> string(3) "dos" ["three"]=> string(4) "tres" } }
```

How do I keep the consistency?

Comment: JS is kind of stupid and expects all arrays to be 0-based with consecutive numerical keys. if you skip a single key anywhere (e.g. `1,2,4,5`), or start non-zero, you get an object.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B explained in a comment, you need to re-index the array to zero-based indexes. In PHP that can be done with [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$encode = json_encode(array_values($data));
```

See as well:

- [Help editing JSON to make an array rather than a 'dictionary' (Jun 2011)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6319203/367456)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) at the options. I think `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` should force constancy.

Comment: I'd say that `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is the opposite of what is tried to achieve here.

Comment: He said he wanted consistency, not that it had to be one or the other. It may not be the best option, but it does resolve the issue I believe.

Comment: Concistentcy in the name of the first index also applies for object properties. `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` does as well create *inconsistent* indexing, just via properties instead of keys. So it only solves half of the problem (the type inconsistency) then the full problem (type *and* index inconsistency) which also highlights that the type inconsistency was only a side-effect of the index inconsistency. However - and not demonstrated in your answer - Fixing the index inconsistency first makes the type inconsistency obsolete. Compare with the examples on http://php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Javascript distinguishes between arrays and objects. PHP only has arrays to cover both types at once.

*Continuously numerically 0-starting PHP arrays* are encoded to Javascript arrays, anything else is encoded to objects.